# UserForm Close button fails after form launched for second time

Tags: excel, excel-2010, userform, vba

I have a `UserForm`, A, with a command button that opens `UserForm` B using the below code:

```
Private Sub cmd_click()
    Me.Hide
    B.Show
End Sub
```

B, when closed via the X button, runs the following:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Unload Me
    A.Show
End Sub
```

After:

- opening B (from A)
- closing B and returning to A
- and then opening B again

The close button on B ceases to work.

`UserForm` A is a menu form that leads to several others, so navigating back and forth between the menus is a pretty basic requirement. This behaviour is reproducible for every form linked from A, as well as for tertiary forms that open from those.

Given my target demographic is of the older generation, I want my `UserForms` to be intuitive to use, which means preserving regular close button functionality.

Does anyone have any info on this? It may be that my google-fu is lacking, but I can't seem to find anyone who has had the same issue. Any input at this stage is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to refer to the 2nd `Userform` in the first as this gives you greater control over the second forms status - you can unset the variable after you have closed the 2nd form and returned to the event handler that instantiated it in the first place. This guarantees that each time you click the button to launch `UserForm2` that you are working with a 'fresh copy'.

Also you should use the `QueryClose` event - see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278635.aspx). This event:

> Occurs before a UserForm closes

You need to be able to be able to control the re-activation of `UserForm1` before the form is disposed.

The `Terminate` event is slightly different:

> Occurs when all references to an instance of an object are removed from memory by setting all variables that refer to the object to Nothing or when the last reference to the object goes out of scope.

In the sample code below I am getting the correct behaviour using a reference to `UserForm2` and handling `QueryClose`.

In this sample code I am using `UserForm1` and `UserForm2` but you can substitue for `A` and `B` in your app:

### Code in `UserForm1`:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_frm2 As UserForm2

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Me.Hide
    Set m_frm2 = New UserForm2
    m_frm2.Show
    Set m_frm2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

### Code in `UserForm2`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    UserForm1.Show
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, will try implementing this now.

Oddly enough, in the interim since asking my question I've turned off all of the queryclose events in each of my forms and swapped to using buttons - Still experiencing the same behaviour!  

I've been using "Unload Me" before showing my next form, because it seems that as soon as I ".Show" a form, that procedure stops executing and instead control yields to the shown form. After the new form is shown, it resumes executing from ".Show" (or "Unload Me").

I notice you call ".Show" before "Unload" - Does this work the same way for you?